# What is an efficient way of rendering a 3 dimensional Conway's Game of Life in Python?

Tags: python, 3d, conways-game-of-life, voxel

I'm curious what a 3D implementation of conway's game of life would look like and thought it would make a fun side project. I'm trying to decide how to render the live/dead cells in 3D.

I'd like all the visuals to occur within an n * n * n cube, like a rubik's cube where all internal cells are also used. The only functionality I really need is the ability to change the colors of the "cells" after a certain time interval. Is there a framework or library that I could use to make the creation of the cube?

I created an implementation with Matplotlib using the "voxels" function but after about 150 boxes it gets too slow to even rotate, and seeing as it is going to be changing every hundredth of a second I dont anticipate mpl could handle it without some optimization that I'm as of yet unaware of. I've been trying to find more information about Python volume rendering techniques for this specific problem but i cant find the term for a "cube made out of cubes" so it has been difficult.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Please repeat the intro tour, especially [on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).  Stack Overflow is not a design or review resource.

Answer (score 1):

The update rule for the game of life (in any dimension) is based on the value of the convolution of the board with a "counting" mask. (all ones in a little 3x3 (or 3x3x3 in your case) region. So, I would suggest using something like `tensorflow` (probably `pytorch` works fine too) and using `tf.nn.conv3d` to do that step fast. You probably need the GPU anyway to be able to rotate the thing quickly.

Comment: Useful information

Comment: That's an interesting approach; I'll definitely take a look at that. If I wanted to go in more of a vanilla python direction how would you approach the 3D rendering portion of this project?